# How to model legacy table(s) with grails scaffolding

Tags: grails, grails-orm

After a week's searching and trying I have to come here with my problem.

I have a legacy system that I need to model with grails **scaffolding**. The system collects report information in the following way:

```
|customer_id|Question_1  |Question_2|...|Question_N|
|123        |A           |Z         |...|D         |
|456        |B           |X         |...|E         |
```

Where the answer sets for questions are:

```
Question 1: A,B,C
Question 2: Z,X,Y
Question N: D,E,F
```

And **N is way over 100 in many this kind of tables**.


**I know that I can model the table in the following ways (don't mind about the syntax)**

#### 1. inList

```
class InformationTable {
    Int customerId
    String question1
    String question2
    .
    .
    String questionN

    static constraints = {
        question1 inList: ['A','B','C']
        question2 inList: ['Z','X','Y']
        .
        .
        questionN inList: ['D','E','F']
    }
}
```

**Or partially with scaffolding by restricting the possible results with custom validators. Scaffolding shows all options in the select boxes of the answers but allows only saving of answers that are their own type:**

#### 2. Custom validator

```
class InformationTable {
    Int customerId
    Answer answer1
    Answer answer2
    .
    .
    answer answerN

    // again, don't mind about the syntax 
    // I wrote this out of memory and will 
    // check the syntax in the evening

    static constraints = {
        answer1 validator: { val, obj ->
            obj.answer1.type == 'question1'
        }
        answer2 validator: { val, obj ->  
            obj.answer2.type == 'question2'
        }   
        .
        .
        answerN validator: { val, obj ->  
            obj.answerN.type == 'questionN'
        }
    }
}

class Answer {
    String name
    String type
}
```

#### Question table in the latter example

```
|type     |name|
|question1|A   |
|question1|B   |
|question1|C   |
|question2|Z   |
|question2|X   |
|question2|Y   |
|question3|D   |
|question3|E   |
|question3|F   |
```

The first option (inList) is a way of doing this with scaffolding, but it requires a lot of work and I don't like that these answer-options aren't in the database.

The second way looks promising, but I don't how to restrict the printed answers printed by scaffolding so that for example answer1 would print only valid options ('A','B','C') to the scaffold dropbox.

**Does anyone know a better way of doing this with scaffolding?**

Comment: It seems you can change the constraints dynamically, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736491/groovy-grails-enhance-a-static-closure